# Cannot dispatch actions initially when app loads

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a mern app and i'm using redux to maintain state of my posts, I want to fetch all data from my api at first run of the app (when the app component loads initially) but I can't achieve it. It only works when I post something and it fetches the post, but it doesn't fetch all the posts from db initially.
After struggling for a day I decided ask here.

This is my component tree:

[image]

In my PostsBody, I want to fetch all the posts from the database whenever the app loads initially (this is not happening) and then whenever there is a change in state like create, delete it should fetch the updated posts (this is happening).
This is my PostsBody component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Post from "./Post";
import { getPostsAction } from '../actions/posts';

const PostsBody = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // fetching posts
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPostsAction);
    }, [dispatch]);

    const posts = useSelector((globalState) => globalState.postsReducer);
    console.log(posts); // intially empty when the app reloads/renders.

    return (
            // simply posts.map to display individual posts
    );
}

export default PostsBody;
```

Action:

```
export const getPostsAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await getAllPosts();
        const action = {
            type: 'GET_ALL',
            payload: data,
        }
        dispatch(action);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

GET CALL:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = "http://localhost:5000/users";

export const getAllPosts = () => axios.get(url);
```

Reducer:

```
const postsReducer = (posts=[], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts, action.payload];
        default: return posts;
    }
}

export default postsReducer;
```

I repeat, the only problem is, it is not fetching all the posts from db initially when the app renders, after that when I create a new post it does fetch that post (not all from db).

Comment: Why don't you use connect instead of useDispatch and useSelector?

Comment: @yahyaparvar what do you mean by 'use connect' ?

Comment: I think you need to actually just call your action creator so it returns the thunk, i.e. `dispatch(getPostsAction());`. Can you clarify what "not all from db" means?

Comment: @DrewReese , like it doesn't fetches all posts from db initially, but when i create a post from react app, it then fetches only this recently created post and not the previous ones stored in the db (not all the posts which are in db).

So you're saying outside of useEffect just call `dispatch(getPostsAction());` ?

Comment: So nothing is being fetched from your DB? Is that a correct understanding? Can you include the asynchronous code that fetches from your DB and dispatches an action to update your state, including the reducer code?

Comment: Yes, nothing is being fetched from db when the app reloads, like the first call to the useEffect. Sure i'll edit the question with saved changes... I have already included the action code, and i dispatch that action in `PostsBody` component.

Comment: So have you checked that your GET request is being made to the backend DB? Are you getting a valid response back? What is updating your state with the "post" you just sent to the backend? This seems like an issue with your backend. Can you include all relevant code in your question. What is sending created posts to the backend DB?

Comment: @DrewReese No i tested my backend with postman, it gave me all the posts which are stored in DB, the get route is working just fine...

Comment: But have you tested hitting that endpoint **from your app**? Does the app correctly make the GET request when you expect it to? And if so, have you checked the value of `data` in the action before you send it to your reducer? Something is dropping the data and you just need to trace the ***entire*** request path from app to backend, back to app, into action, into reducer, into state, into selector, back to UI.

Comment: @DrewReese Okay i'll do that, i tried console logging the `data` in action but I can't see it in console.. any tips?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228099/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-dev1ce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

It doesn't appear as though you are invoking the `getPostsAction` action creator correctly. Also, with ***only*** `dispatch` in the `useEffect`'s dependency array the hook callback will only be invoked once when the component mounts.

## Solution

Invoke the `getPostsAction` action.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPostsAction()); // <-- invoke
}, [dispatch]);
```

Now this still only solves for fetching posts from the DB when the component mounts, but not when new posts are POST'd to your backend.

I've looked at your actions and state. Normally you would include another variable in the `useEffect` dependency array to trigger the effect callback to execute again, but I think a simpler way is possible. Instead of POST'ing the new post and dispatching the `CREATE` action you should POST the new "post" and immediately GET all posts and dispatch the `GET_ALL` action instead with ***that*** data.

```
export const createPostAction = (newPostData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await createPost(newPostData);
    getAllPosts()(dispatch);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

I've basic familiarity with Thunks, but if the above doesn't work then you may need to duplicate *some* behavior, or factor it out into some common utility code used by both action creators.

```
export const createPostAction = (newPostData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await createPost(newPostData);
    const { data } = await getAllPosts();
    const action = {
        type: 'GET_ALL',
        payload: data,
    }
    dispatch(action);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```